# Installing on old laptop

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install Kubuntu on **8 YO Toshiba laptop**, but keep getting  this error message:

```
SMBIOS implementation newer than 2.8 not fully supported
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Kubuntu are you trying to install? My guess it's 12.04 try another version like 13.10 and see if that works.

Comment: There is a confirmed bug of this on launchpad for Ubuntu 12.04, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1236233

Comment: I'm trying to install 13.10, but I've had the same problem with other flavours of Ubuntu. Graeme

Comment: Please mark the bug as affecting you too. The bug appears to be fixed in Ubuntu 14.04, try installing that. Or maybe update your download of 13.10? (I don't know when you downloaded it, but if it was a while ago, redownload it)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a complete Linux newbie. Been using Windows for years, but I now have a spare laptop and decided to install Linux to give it a try. So far all I've had is errors, and I don't really want to try a Beta 14.04. Might wait until the stable version comes out. Happy to mark this bug as affecting me, if I can figure out how to do it. Graeme